# does on_raw_reaction_add() only work once per message?

Tags: python, discord.py

so I am making a discord bot where the bot has a list and I want the user to be able to react to change it.

This is what I have came up with so far.

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    global msg
    global msg_id
    global list_of_embeds
    amount = 0
    if payload.message_id == msg_id:
        if payload.emoji.name == "➡️":
            await msg.edit(embed=list_of_embeds[amount])
            amount += 1
```

This is just a prototype of what I want the real code to be, but it is not working. It works fine the first time I react, but after that every time I unreact and react again it doesn't change. The msg variable is a variable containing the message, msg_id is a variable containing the message id, and list_of_embeds is a list that contains the embeds that I want to send. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you missed the `on_raw_reaction_remove(payload)` event, that is why there are no changes.

Comment: Ok, I will try that, thanks.

Comment: If this is for a single command, it would be better to use a [reaction check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=def%20check%20reaction#discord.Client.wait_for) like in [the question linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090668/reaction-check-with-discord-py)